# Where are each of the job shrines?

Tags: octopath-traveler

When I was wandering around, I stumbled across a shrine that gave me the ability to add that class to my characters as an alternate class. Since then I've been wandering around, trying to find all of them. It seems like, so far, the base 8 are going to be in the offshoots of each town, towards the chapter 2 towns, but I've still been having trouble finding those.

Supposedly, there are also 4 hidden jobs. Are those obtainable from shrines as well?

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for. A lot of the information for the game is still hot off the presses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the picture of all the base class shrines + the 4 advanced ones:

[image: Shrines]

The job of each shrine corresponds with the starting city of the same "biome" type i.e: scholar -> city: Atlasdam, biome: flatlands, shrine: Western Noblecourt flats.

In the example above, it would be [Atlasdam]-> North Atlasdam Flats -> Western Noblecourt Flats -> [Shrine of the Sage]

The maps for each shrine are as follows:

- Shrine of the Healer (Apothecary) is in East Saintsbridge Traverse
- Shrine of the Flamebearer (Cleric) is in Western Stillsnow Wilds
- Shrine of the Lady of Grace (Dancer) is in Northern Wellspring Sands
- Shrine of the Huntress (Hunter) is in East Victors Hollow Trail
- Shrine of the Trader (Merchant) is in Moonstruck Coast
- Shrine of the Sage (Scholar) is in Western Noblecourt Flats
- Shrine of the Prince of Thieves (Thief) is in South Quarrycrest Pass
- Shrine of the Thunderblade (Warrior) is in North Stonegard Pass

For the advanced jobs, they have their own lvl 50 dungeon, so it's going to take a while to get there.

The maps for these shrines are as follows:

- Shrine of the Runeblade (Runelord) is in West Everhold Pass
- Shrine of the Archmagus (Sorcerer) is in East Duskbarrow Trail
- Shrine of the Starseer (Starseer) is in Western Wispermill Flats
- Shrine of the Warbringer (Warmaster) is in North Riverford Traverse

Comment: Please inline the image. Additionally it may help to list off the text region names for each class so people can parse the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an in-depth guide that tells you exactly how to get to each location, down to the exact directions within the game -- [Octopath Shrines Guide](https://www.gameskinny.com/uem9l/octopath-traveler-guide-complete-shrine-locations-list).

It's already helped me quite a bit with picking these up. Hopefully, it'll help you all out as well.